# Cast AlignedBox double to AlignedBox int

Tags: c++, geometry, eigen

I'm trying to use Eigen AlignedBox. Specifically, I'm trying to cast a box of double into an int one, by using AlignedBox::cast

```
AlignedBox<double, 2> aabbox2d = AlignedBox<double, 2>(Vector2d(0.52342, 2.12315), Vector2d(3.87346, 4.72525));
aabbox2d.cast<AlignedBox<int, 2>>();
auto minx = aabbox2d.min().x();
```

Anyway, when the execution gets to min() I get an assert:

```
Assertion failed: (((SizeAtCompileTime == Dynamic && (MaxSizeAtCompileTime==Dynamic || size<=MaxSizeAtCompileTime)) || SizeAtCompileTime == size) && size>=0), function resize, file /Users/max/Developer/Stage/Workspace/AutoTools3D/dep/libigl/external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h, line 312.
```

Note that this is different from casting a matrix scalar to another one. An object is implied.
Supposedly I'm not doing the cast correctly. Does someone know the right way?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting the documentation for [`AlignedBox::cast`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AlignedBox.html#aa5b17581b51c7fb3a8396263dcaa7d59) shows that the template argument to `cast` is defined as `template<typename NewScalarType>` and the return value is `*this with scalar type casted to NewScalarType`. Thus the `cast` function does not modify the existing instance of the box, but returns a new one. To make your example work you need to store the returned instance like follows:

```
AlignedBox<double, 2> aabbox2d = AlignedBox<double, 2>(Vector2d(0.52342, 2.12315), Vector2d(3.87346, 4.72525));
AlignedBox<int, 2>  casted = aabbox2d.cast<int>();
const int minx = casted.min().x();
```

You can play with this here: https://godbolt.org/z/ozE4rzebb

As a side note: as the [documentation states](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html), when working with `Eigen` one should refrain from using `auto` (probably not a problem in this case though)

Comment: aww thank you for this. Actually used auto because didn't know what type to expect...

Comment: ...and now discovered Eigen just takes the integer part without doing rounding, that's what I wanted to know in the beginning...